# Is there a way to look up all questions I have commented on?

Tags: support, comments, profile-page

I can get direct access to questions I have posted.
I can get direct access to questions I have answered.

But I can't get to questions/answers where I have only posted a comment.

Is there a way to view all posts containing my comments?

Comment: Check this [once](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/398388/all-comments-that-you-have-ever-made-limited-to-sede-restrictions)!

Comment: If the post or your comment have been removed, I don't think so.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar How can I access all of my comments on StackOverflow now? It seems after the recent update, that option is removed

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your profile →  All actions →  comments.

If you want to see all your comments across all SE sites, do this from http://www.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How can I access all of my comments on StackOverflow now? It seems after the recent update, that option is removed

Comment: @Ahmad I can still see all your comments at https://stackoverflow.com/users/736172/ahmad?tab=activity or for all of SE, https://stackexchange.com/users/381489/ahmad?tab=activity

Answer (score 9):

Use the data explorer.

```
SELECT id, creationdate, text, postid AS [Post Link]
FROM Comments
WHERE UserId = '736172'
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/605674/comments-for-ahmad736172

Comment: This works if data explorer has received latest data.